# Someone is actually able to exchange NDEF messages in real world apps?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I implemented an app offering an interaction between two devices based on Android Beaming.

In my current implementation, the beaming functionality is unusable. When the two devices touch each other and one of them is ready to beam, a screen showing "touch to beam" (or something similar, I have the devices set to the Italian language) appears (on both of them, which is strange). When I tap on "touch to beam" 99.9% of the times, Android asks me to move the devices closer, but they are actually touching each other (the backs of the phones touch each other).

The two devices are a Nexus 9 (with Android 5, latest) and a LG G2 (Android 4.4). Communication from LG G2 towards the Nexus is less annoying, let's say that it has a 'failure' rate of around 80%.

This is the bare code I use for beaming inside of an Activity:

```
...
nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(new NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "push message callback - message created");
            return createApprovalRequestNDEFmsg();
        }
    }, this);


nfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(new NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent event) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "push complete");
            waitForClientMessage();
        }
...


protected void waitForClientMessage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for the reply message from the client.");
    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, readTagFilters, null);
}
    }, this);
```

The NDEF message is around 100 bytes in size. In the `waitForClientMessage` method the Activity (running on the Nexus) sets a `PendingIntent` for receiving the NFC push message from the client (running on the LG G2).

In the 0.1% occasions where the beaming is successful, the correct activity on the receiving phone is created by the OS. As I said, the return message (from LG G2 -> Nexus) is usually easier to receive.

What is your experience with this Android Beaming? Did you have to implement something special to have a vaguely usable interaction between two devices?

May be I need to add more information, but I don't know which one since everything is so conceptually simple and the API very very limited.